# Feature given by class is already given by race. What to do RAW?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, racial-traits

I have a player in my game with an Aasimar Warlock with a Celestial Patron. At 6th level, Celestial Patron grants "... resistance to radiant damage, and when you cast a spell that deals radiant or fire damage, you add your Charisma modifier to one radiant or fire damage roll of that spell against one of its targets." Aasimar race also grants radiant damage resistance. Is there a rule (RAW) that tells what to do in cases like this?

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Just to be clear, this being closed as a duplicate doesn't reflect badly on you. It will be useful for others who might try to find this information and ask it the same what you did. Take the [tour](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/tour) if you haven't already and see the [help center](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/help) if you need more guidance. Good Luck and Happy Gaming!

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### You have resistance to radiant damage (nothing more)

The rule on [Damage and Vulnerability](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#DamageandVulnerability) states:

> **Multiple instances of resistance or vulnerability that affect the same damage type count as only one instance**. For example, if a creature has resistance to fire damage as well as resistance to all nonmagical damage, the damage of a nonmagical fire is reduced by half against the creature, not reduced by three-quarters.

You are receiving the same benefit twice, one from your character's race, and one from its class. Unfortunately, one of these is essentially "wasted" in that it provides no further benefit beyond what you already have from the first instance.

Comment: So there is no rule like the one for skills when you have the same proficiency with a class and with a background? PHB states that you can choose another option from the list of skills. In this particular case there is no list to choose from so I'm doubting there is a RAW rule.

Comment: @Caesar The list of skills provided by a class can overlap with those list of skills provided by a background. You can pick skills efficiently so that you don't "double up" between the two. It sounds like you're trying to extrapolate this to class/race features. These are major components that are unique to that class or race. If certain benefits of those features overlap, you are, unfortunately, stuck with that inefficiency.

Comment: @CesarHernandez there are some halfbaked rules, for example what happens when you have a proficieny in a skill and also a toolset profciency. Xanthars Guide recommends giving an advantage on the roll, but its just an "its up to the DM".
Here this doesnt fit, and I surely wont go the way towards making an immunity out of a restistance, cause it is just to powerful.
If you want to make your player happy, maybe add a second use of "Healing Hands" per day.. Would sound fair to me